# Why does this code not display the 5 random Titles I set?

Tags: batch-file, random

```
set /a titleran=0
set /a titleran+=(%RANDOM%*5/32768)+1)
if %titleran%==1 title The Lands of Sweet v.a.0: Now with basic functions
if %titleran%==2 title The Lands of Sweet v.a.0: Hey! Look behind you!
if %titleran%==3 title The Lands of Sweet v.a.0: The Lands of Sweet v.a.0: The Lands of Sweet v.a.0: The Lands of Sweet v.a.0: 
if %titleran%==4 title The Lands of Sweet v.a.0: insert funny joke here
if %titleran%==5 title The Lands of Sweet v.a.0: Thots are temporary, The Sweet is eternal
```

This is the code that produces a random number from 1-5 then sets the title based on the selected number

BTW it actually only keeps displaying the fifth title

Comment: your first line is unneccessary, and your secund line is incorrect syntax - it contains a closing parenthesis that doesn't belong. It should be: `set /a titleran=(%RANDOM%*5/32768)+1` or `set /a titleran=%RANDOM% %%5 +1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler method however:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "titles={Now with basic functions}{Hey! Look Behind You!}{The Lands of Sweet v.a.0: The Lands of Sweet v.a.0: The Lands of Sweet v.a.0:}{insert funny joke here}{Thots are temporary, The Sweet is eternal}"
For /F "Delims=" %%# in ('Set /A "t#=%Random% %%5 + 1"') Do Set "Title=For /F "Tokens=%%# Delims={}" %%t in ("%titles%") Do Title %%t"
%Title%
```

define the possible titles as a list and extract a title from the list with a randomised index number.

Comment: will it still work if I put everything in lowercase, right?

Comment: case is a matter of user preference where commands are concerned